# Entity Database not committing add or save changes c# winform

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, entity

This is a simple winform im creating that when you click a button it will gather data from a combo box and then add data to a database here is the button event code.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database1Entities5 entities = new Database1Entities5();
    int personOneID = entities.People.Where(p => p.Name == _PersonOne).FirstOrDefault().PersonID;
    int personTwoID = entities.People.Where(p => p.Name == _PersonTwo).FirstOrDefault().PersonID;
    int amount = _Amount;
    int TypeID = entities.Types.Where(t => t.Name == _Type).FirstOrDefault().TypeID;
    Money m = Money.CreateMoney(personOneID, personTwoID, TypeID, _Amount, DateTime.Now, CommentTextBox.Text);
    entities.Moneys.AddObject(m);
    entities.SaveChanges();
   // 
}
```

when i click the button nothing happens, during debuging the Money m is created fine; i have no idea whats going on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My mistake i thought it was going to auto format

Comment: just a comment to the code, you shouldn't use OrDefault() if you're not checking for null anyway. It will give you weird Null Reference Exception which are always a pain to track down where a Sequence did not match any elements exception is more meaningful.

Comment: The code you've posted here is just fine, it should persist the money entity. I do find it strange though you're passing in the ids of the people and not just the entities.